# How to have a generator class in shader glsl with amplify shader editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

i want to create a shader that can cover a surface with "circles" from many random positions.
the circles keep growing until all surface covered with them.
here my first try with amplify shader editor.
the problem is i don't know how make this shader that create array of "point maker" with random positions.also i want to controll circles with
c# example:

```
point_maker = new point_maker[10];
point_maker[1].position = Vector2.one;
point_maker[1].scale = 1;
```

and etc ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Heads-up: That's probably not the way to do what you're looking for, as every pixel in your shader would need to loop over all your input points, while each of those pixels will only be covered by one at most. It's a classic case of embracing the benefits of the parallel nature of shaders. (The keyword for me here is 'random', as in 'random looking').

There's 2 distinct problems here: generating circles, and masking them.
I would go onto generating a grid out of your input space (most likely your UV coordinates so I'll assume that from here), by taking the fractional part of the coords scaled by some value: UV (usually) go between 0 and 1, so if you want 100 circles you'd multiply the coord by 10. You now have a grid of 100 pieces of UVs, where you can do something similar to what you have to generate the circle (tip: dot product a vector on itself gives the square distance, which is much cheaper to compute).

You want some randomness, so you need to add some offset to the center of the circle. You need some sort of random number (there might be some in ASE I can't remember, or make one your own - there's plenty of that you look online) that is unique per cell of the grid. To do this you'd input the remainder of your frac() as value to your hash/random method. You also need to limit that offset depending on the radius of the circle so it doesn't touch the sides of the cell. You can overlay more than one layer of circles if you want more coverage as well.

Second step is to figure out if you want to display those circles at all, and for this you could make the drawing conditional to the distance from the center of the circle to an input coordinate you provide to the shader, by some threshold. (it doesn't have to be an 'if' condition per se, it could be clamping the value to the bg color or something)

I'm making a lot of assumptions on what you want to do here, and if you have stronger conditions on the point distribution you might be better off rendering quads to a render texture for example, but that's a whole other topic :)

Comment: tanx!! there is a lot of searching and testing for me now. but i'm going to test last idea of yours. render circles to texture as mask into the shader.